# Non blocking subprocess with Celluloid

Tags: ruby, celluloid

What is the best way to spawn a subprocess without blocking the actor ?

My goal is to run multiple commands, and when they are done, get the output and the exit code.
I tried this, but obviously, the popen call is blocking:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'celluloid/current'
require 'celluloid/io'

class MyProcessLauncher
    include Celluloid::IO

    def run
        every(1) { puts "tick" }

        every(5) {
            puts "Starting subprocess"
            ::IO.popen("sleep 10 && echo 'subprocess done'", :err=>[:child, :out]) { |io|
                puts io.read
            }
            puts $?.exitstatus
        }
    end
end

MyProcessLauncher.new.run
sleep
```

The output is :

```
tick
tick
tick
tick
Starting subprocess
subprocess done
0
tick
Starting subprocess
```

but I expect five 'tick' between each 'Starting subprocess'...

Thanks !

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Question updated with output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `defer` or use a `future` if you want the return value.

### `defer` ( easy if you need no return )

In your `every(5)` block, to use `defer`, wrap your `popen` call (including the exit status display call) with `defer {}`

### `future` ( a bit more complicated )

There are several ways to implement this approach. My suggestion would be to move the contents of `every(5)` to its own method, and initialize an array `@futures` or similar when starting `MyProcessLauncher` ... then use this inside the `every(5)` call:

```
@futures = future.new_method
```

Also, add a new loop to process your futures. After `every(5)` add a new handler ( either another `every` loop, or an `async` call to a processor method which is recursive ) to process your values, essentially doing this:

```
value = @futures.pop.value if @futures.any?
```

I'd ask a follow up question about futures if you have trouble and can't find examples of how to process futures. Otherwise, there you have two ways to handle `popen` calls without blocking.

Comment: Thanks ! Both method are working fine. I also found another solution by using a Pool of dedicated Actor to run the popen code.